# Got error while building apk on buildozer

Tags: android, python-3.x, opencv, kivy, buildozer

I am working on a kivy android app and while building the apk got the below error. The error is saying that opencv requires android sdk release version 14 or newer but when i check the version where i can find the sdk install path i can find it as 30.0.4. Below are the logs

```
  STDOUT:
-- Looking for ccache - not found
-- OpenCV disables pkg-config to avoid using of host libraries. Consider using PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR to specify target SYSROOT
-- libjpeg-turbo: VERSION = 1.5.3, BUILD = opencv-4.0.1-libjpeg-turbo
-- Android: fixup -g compiler option from Android toolchain
-- Update variable ANDROID_SDK from environment: /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
CMake Error at cmake/android/OpenCVDetectAndroidSDK.cmake:176 (message):
  Android SDK Tools: OpenCV requires Android SDK Tools revision 14 or newer.

  Use BUILD_ANDROID_PROJECTS=OFF to prepare Android project files without
  building them
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:780 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/myapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/opencv/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/myapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/opencv/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,numpy,python-opencv,matplotlib,datetime,opencv==master --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/myapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     HOSTNAME = '06dd908deae1'
#     PWD = '/home/myapp'
#     HOME = '/root'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     TERM = 'xterm'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/.local/bin/'
#     OLDPWD = '/home'
#     _ = '/root/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     LC_CTYPE = 'C.UTF-8'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I checked the sdk version under below path

```
/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/platform-tools/source.properties
```

and it shows Pkg.UserSrc=false & Pkg.Revision=30.0.4

I have update the builozer.spec as below:

```
android.sdk = 30.0.4

# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 19c

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.sdk_path = /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
```

Need help on how to fix this!!

Comment: Also, adding some more reference info ``` root@06dd908deae1:/home/myapp# cat /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/source.properties
Pkg.Revision=2.0
Pkg.Path=cmdline-tools;2.0
Pkg.Desc=Android SDK Command-line Tools```

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the ```android.sdk``` line in ```buildozer.spec``` file? In that case it will take the latest SDK version.